# How to go about waterproofing a wifi antenna?

Tags: wifi

So you can purchase a pretty powerful wifi antenna for $50. To make it waterproof would cost you upwards of $500 and force you to go looking for questionable suppliers.

What material can you use to waterproof a wifi antenna, without hindering any of it's radio strength?

Would PVC work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buy one that is already waterproof. IP65 for example. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code

Comment: Omni-directional: http://thewifishop.net/wifi-aerials/high-gain-outdoor-15dbi-omni-wireless-wifi-antenna/prod_173.html
Directional: http://www.wifigear.co.uk/24ghz-high-gain-12dbi-directional-antenna